# Nokogiri recursively get all children

Tags: ruby, search, xhtml, nokogiri

### The Problem

I am running some statistics against various URLS. I want to find the top level element with the most concentrated number of children. The method that I would like to follow is to identify all top level elements and then determine what percentage of all the elements on the page belong to it.

### Goal

- Recursively get all children of a given element.

Inputs: a Nokogiri Element

Outputs: an array of Nokogiri Elements OR the count of total number of children

### Setup

- Ruby 1.9.2
- Nokogiri gem

### What I ended up coming up with (this works, but isn't as pretty as my chosen answer below)

```
getChildCount(elem)
    children = elem.children
    return 0 unless children and children.count > 0
    child_count = children.count
    children.each do |child|
        child_count += getChildCount(child)
    end
    child_count
end
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the code you've written, and the problem you've encountered when trying to get it to work.

Comment: You really need to clarify what your input is, what your desired output is, and what you have tried to code yourself to do it, or what problems you are having.

Comment: Yeah, you and Tin Man are right on that. Hopefully this clears it up. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 33, accepted):

the [traverse method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#traverse-instance_method) yields the current node and all children to a block, recursively.

```
# if you would like it to be returned as an array, rather than each node being yielded to a block, you can do this
result = []
doc.traverse {|node| result << node }
result

# or, 
require 'enumerator'
result = doc.enum_for(:traverse).map
```

Comment: +1 (when I get more votes in 2 hours). I had not previously seen this method. Thanks!

Comment: the enum_for example is awesome!

Answer (score 10):

```
# Non-recursive
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def descendant_elements
    xpath('.//*')
  end
end

# Recursive 1
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def descendant_elements
    element_children.map{ |kid|
      [kid, kid.descendant_elements]
    }.flatten
  end
end

# Recursive 2
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def descendant_elements
    kids = element_children.to_a
    kids.concat(kids.map(&:descendant_elements)).flatten
  end
end
```