# extracting runs of text with Mechanize/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

Is there a sensible way to extract each run of text in a Mechanize-parsed HTML document, so that (for example):

```
<p>Here is <b>some</b> text<p>
```

is broken into three elements:

```
Here is
some
text
```

?  My hunch is that there's a simple technique using recursive CSS search and/or #flatten, but I've not figured it out yet.

Comment: What do you define as a "run" of text? Do you just want all the text content as a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nokogiri text node contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992540/nokogiri-text-node-contents)

Comment: not a duplicate -- "here is some text" is the text of the outer <p> element, "some" is the text of the inner <b> element.  I want each _run_ of text to be separated out.

Comment: It appears that what you mean by "run" of text is the contents of each text node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from an answer in "[Nokogiri recursively get all children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076190/nokogiri-recursively-get-all-children#10077772)":

```
result = []
doc.traverse { |node| result << node.text if node.text? }
```

That should give you the array `["Here is ", "some", " text"]`.

"[Getting Mugged by Nokogiri](http://techiferous.com/2009/12/getting-mugged-by-nokogiri/)" discusses `traverse`.

Comment: p.s. the "getting mugged by Nokogiri" post is great -- thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the contents of each text node, you can do this:

```
doc.search('//text()').map(&:text)
```

The only downside to this (and to the other answer) is that you get all the whitespace between elements as well. If you want to suppress this, you can do this:

```
doc.search('//text()').map(&:text).delete_if{|x| x !~ /\w/}
```

This removes all elements that don't contain a word character.