# How to see if one Nokogiri::XML::Node contains parts of another Nokogiri::XML::Node?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri, stanford-nlp

Using ruby Nokogiri I have a `Nokogiri::XML::Node` object (ConstituencyXMLNode inherits from `Nokogiri::XML::Node`) that is a tree object like such:

```
#(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc3c8 {
  name = "PP",
  children = [
    #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc3dc { name = "IN", children = [ #(Text "out")] }),
    #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc3f0 {
      name = "PP",
      children = [
        #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc404 { name = "IN", children = [ #(Text "of")] }),
        #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc418 {
          name = "NP",
          children = [
            #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc42c { name = "JJ", children = [ #(Text "non-living")] }),
            #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc440 { name = "NNS", children = [ #(Text "resources")] })]
          })]
      })]
  })
```

We will call it `pp_leaf`

and I want to compare and see if portions of this node are included within this other partial Nokogiri::XML::Node:

```
#(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc3f0 {
  name = "PP",
  children = [
    #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc404 { name = "IN", children = [ #(Text "of")] }),
    #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc418 {
      name = "NP",
      children = [
        #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc42c { name = "JJ", children = [ #(Text "non-living")] }),
        #(ConstituencyXMLNode:0xc440 { name = "NNS", children = [ #(Text "resources")] })]
      })]
  })
```

We will call this node `current_leaf`.

It seems that [`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` has the comparison tools I am looking for](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-at_xpath:%7E:text=include%3F(node),-click%20to%20toggle), but I am unsure of how to convert a `Nokogiri::XML::Node` to a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`.  None of the operators on `Nokogiri::XML::Node` appear to have the comparison operators I need to match if one set contains the other.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the desired outcome? What do you mean contains parts of another Node? Is this any part or an entire hierarchical subset or superset? Is the nesting depth important or can it be anywhere? BTW `children` is a `NodeSet` and `Node` defines comparable methods including `==` and `<=>`. Can you explain what "comparison tools" you want to use from `NodeSet`  that `Node` does not provide?

Comment: I want to check if the larger first node has parts that match the first element.  If it does I return true versus false.  I need to match on both the `name` attribute and it's containing `text`.  From `NodeSet` I was thinking of using the `.include?()` function.

Comment: So `pp_leaf == current_leaf || pp_leaf.children.include?(current_leaf)`? You could perform this recursively if necessary.

Comment: I found a way to do it with: `pp_leaf.xpath('.//*').include?(current_leaf)` thanks to this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077311/3448554

It breaks the tree down into an array which lets you check if the node is a member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it with:

```rb
pp_leaf.xpath('.//*').include?(current_leaf)`
```

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077311/3448554).  It breaks the node tree down into an array which lets you check if the node is a member.